# get data attribute and set new value

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I cannot get my code to work..

i select my elements, and try to get the value of a data attribute, and change the value accordingly.

Html:

```
<div class="flipUpMenu" id="flipUpMenuBox" data-flip="false"></div>
<button id="flipElement">Flip Up </button>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //buttons
    var btnFlip = $("#flipElement");

    //elements
    var flipUpElement = $("flipUpMenuBox");

    btnFlip.click(function(){
        if(flipUpElement.data('flip') === 'false'){
            alert("flip true");
        }else{
            alert("flip false");
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of alerts, i would want to set the data-flip to either true or false.
As a way of toggleing it.

Comment: Did you mean `flipUpElement.data('flip', true)`?

Comment: @TheAlpha yep... and that wont work..

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Make sure you've used `$("#flipUpMenuBox")` not `$("flipUpMenuBox")` as I can see in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("flipUpMenuBox")` need to be `$("#flipUpMenuBox")`

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var btnFlip = $("#flipElement");
  var flipUpElement = $("#flipUpMenuBox");
  btnFlip.click(function(){
    if(flipUpElement.attr('data-flip') == 'false'){ // use ==
      flipUpElement.attr('data-flip','true');
    }else{
      flipUpElement.attr('data-flip','false');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipUpMenu" id="flipUpMenuBox" data-flip="false"></div>
<button id="flipElement">Flip Up </button>
```

Comment: @andrelange91  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
// Select the element by id

var flipUpElement = $("#flipUpMenuBox");

// Set the data

flipUpElement.data('flip', true);

// Get the data and log it

console.log(flipUpElement.data('flip'));
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flipUpElement = $("#flipUpMenuBox");
    flipUpElement.data('flip', true);
    console.log(flipUpElement.data('flip'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipUpMenu" id="flipUpMenuBox" data-flip="false"></div>
```

Also, make sure you've used `$("#flipUpMenuBox")` not `$("flipUpMenuBox")` to select the element, I can see you've used `$("flipUpMenuBox")`.

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer about your selection?

Comment: yep updated them, but it still doesn't change the code to show true or false, although console.log does say true or false, when i toggle...

Comment: Just check this [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2pcfj9m1/2/). Don't want to add code here for this test.

Comment: Why don't you want to put the code here in a Stack Snippet?

Comment: @Barmar, I thought it's a one time simple code so not polute the SO, anyways, I've added now.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(flipUpElement.data('flip') === 'false'){
```

won't work as intended. jQuery `.data()` tries to parse the data attribute as JSON, and if that succeeds it returns the parsed value. So `"false"` will be converted to a boolean `false` instead of returning the string.

So you should change it to:

```
if(flipUpElement.data('flip')) {
    flipUpElement.data('flip', false);
} else {
    flipUpElement.data('flip', true);
}
```

or more simply:

```
flipUpElement.data('flip', !flipUpElement.data('flip'));
```

And as others have pointed out, you left out the `#` in the selector used to set `flipUpElement`.